# Suse 13.1 boot disk

Tags: opensuse, opensuse-13.1

I have downloaded openSuse 13.1. I have burned a DVD and attempted to load the disk. I find that I need to make a suse boot disk to load the operating system on the laptop. Being new to this, be specific please on how I can make a boot disk to load the software on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The DVD you have burned should be a sufficient boot disk. You just need to tell your laptop you wish to boot from CD at startup, generally this can be done from the bios or a F* key, When you start your laptop on the splash screen it should say press FX for boot menu, press that key at start up and you should be given a option to boot from your DVD drive.